# data manipulation example from wide to long in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've just placed a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42666009/how-to-gather-dataframe-column-into-key-value-pairs-as-row-in-python) and got an answer but recognised, that by adding a new column to a DataFrame the presented solution fails as the problem is a bit different.

I want to go from here:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1, 2],
                   'Value_2013': [100, 200],
                   'Value_2014': [245, 300],
                   'Value_2016': [200, float('NaN')]})

print(df)

    ID  Value_2013  Value_2014  Value_2016
0   1         100         245       200.0
1   2         200         300         NaN
```

to:

```
df_new = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2],
                       'Year': [2013, 2014, 2016, 2013, 2014],
                       'Value': [100, 245, 200, 200, 300]})

print(df_new)

    ID  Value  Year
0   1    100  2013
1   1    245  2014
2   1    200  2016
3   2    200  2013
4   2    300  2014
```

Any ideas how I can face this challenge?

Comment: all the column from the original is going to call Value_year?

Comment: yes.. however melt function looks to be fine! thank you all for the great  answers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`pandas.melt()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html) method gets you halfway there. After that it's just some minor cleaning up.

```
df = pd.melt(df, id_vars='ID', var_name='Year', value_name='Value')
df['Year'] = df['Year'].map(lambda x: x.split('_')[1])
df = df.dropna().astype(int).sort_values(['ID', 'Year']).reset_index(drop=True)
df = df.reindex_axis(['ID', 'Value', 'Year'], axis=1)
```

---

```
print(df)
   ID  Value  Year
0   1    100  2013
1   1    245  2014
2   1    200  2016
3   2    200  2013
4   2    300  2014
```

Answer (score 3):

You need add [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) first:

```
df = df.set_index('ID')
df.columns = df.columns.str.split('_', expand=True)
df = df.stack().rename_axis(['ID','Year']).reset_index()
df.Value = df.Value.astype(int)
#if order of columns is important
df = df.reindex_axis(['ID','Value','Year'], axis=1)
print (df)
   ID  Value  Year
0   1    100  2013
1   1    245  2014
2   1    200  2016
3   2    200  2013
4   2    300  2014
```

Answer (score 1):

## Leveraging Multi Indexing in Pandas

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from collections import OrderedDict

df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1, 2],
                   'Value_2013': [100, 200],
                   'Value_2014': [245, 300],
                   'Value_2016': [200, float('NaN')]})


# Set ID column as Index
df = df.set_index('ID')

# unstack all columns, swap the levels in the row index 
# and convert series to df
df = df.unstack().swaplevel().to_frame().reset_index()
# Rename columns as desired
df.columns = ['ID', 'Year', 'Value']

# Transform the year values from Value_2013 --> 2013 and so on
df['Year'] = df['Year'].apply(lambda x : x.split('_')[1]).astype(np.int)

# Sort by ID
df = df.sort_values(by='ID').reset_index(drop=True).dropna()

print(df)
   ID  Year  Value
0   1  2013  100.0
1   1  2014  245.0
2   1  2016  200.0
3   2  2013  200.0
4   2  2014  300.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is pd.wide_to_long(). Admittedly it doesn't give you *exactly* the same output but you can clean up as needed.

```
pd.wide_to_long(df, ['Value_',], i='', j='Year')

          ID  Value_
    Year            
NaN 2013   1     100
    2013   2     200
    2014   1     245
    2014   2     300
    2016   1     200
    2016   2     NaN
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity: is this the *exact* output of the code on your system? Due to the ``NaN`` in the ``Value_`` column, I'd have expected the dtype to be automatically converted to ``float`` (the lack of an integer ``NaN`` is something that I hate so much about Pandas). Has that changed in the version that you use?

Comment: That's exactly what I get with Pandas 0.16.2.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another soution (two steps):

```
In [31]: x = df.set_index('ID').stack().astype(int).reset_index(name='Value')

In [32]: x
Out[32]:
   ID     level_1  Value
0   1  Value_2013    100
1   1  Value_2014    245
2   1  Value_2016    200
3   2  Value_2013    200
4   2  Value_2014    300

In [33]: x = x.assign(Year=x.pop('level_1').str.extract(r'(\d{4})', expand=False))

In [34]: x
Out[34]:
   ID  Value  Year
0   1    100  2013
1   1    245  2014
2   1    200  2016
3   2    200  2013
4   2    300  2014
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is with the [pivot_longer](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.pivot.pivot_longer) function from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/), using the `.value` placeholder:

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor

(df
.pivot_longer(
   index = "ID", 
   names_to=(".value", "Year"), 
   names_sep="_", 
   sort_by_appearance=True)
.dropna()
)

   ID  Year  Value
0   1  2013  100.0
1   1  2014  245.0
2   1  2016  200.0
3   2  2013  200.0
4   2  2014  300.0
```

The `.value` keeps the part of the column associated with it as header, while the rest goes into the `Year` column.